# Angular upgrade to 16 throws many unknown elements errors from AppModule

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, upgrade, angular16

I have upgraded my project from Angular 15 to 16. After this for many ,compilation errors for unknown errors. Tried many solutions like adding schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA], but still error.

```
 error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ui-switch'.
1. If 'ui-switch' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ui-switch' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Been with this error for a week no clue which cause these errors.
basically the components declared in AppModule throws these errors.
But when i declare these in SharedModule error is gone
With same AppModule the project was working fine with Angular 15.

Comment: Did you figure out an answer for this? I am having the same issue, and after declaring the component explicitly in SharedModule, the error is gone. 

But I am wondering, why only after updating to Angular 16? Why not before then? What changed? Before Angular 15, the code was working fine.